# jquery image preload vs javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, load

i'm tring to find the best way to preload image for a carousel
in my jquery function i do

```
$('<img />').attr({ 'src': imgurl }).appendTo(currentli).hide().load(function() {                   
                   console.log("preload!");
                });
```

searching for the best way to do it, i found old 2008 questions where it was suggest to use

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = imgurl;

document.body.appendChild( img );
img.onload = function() {
console.log("preload!");
}
```

any difference using jquery and javascript? any other suggestion?

Comment: Since jQuery _is_ JavaScript, I'd imagine there's no difference.

Comment: The difference is loading in the jquery library just to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

the simple javascript version first loads the image in the memory as the src is defined and then you add it to the DOM..

the jquery version first adds it to the DOM and then loads the image.. that's all the diff these have

after comment update:-

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = imgurl;

$('<img />').attr({ 'src': imgurl }).appendTo(currentli).hide().load(function() {                   
                   console.log("preload!");
                });
```

by doing this you can load the image before actually it was being added to the DOM

Comment: so since i need image to be loaded before i use it would be bettere JS version, how can i mix the 2? i mean after creating the image with js append the new obj img with jquery

Answer (score 0):

yeah, wait until the window is ready with the the window load event, and then display the actual div element that contains the photos AND run the functionality. Something like...

```
$(window).load(function(){ 
  displayAndRunMyCarousel();
});
```